# Anonymous function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

Maybe this sounds ridiculous question, but it is for me still not exactly clear the difference between where the `#` of a anonymous function should come. For example in this example i filter the divisors of a positive number:

```
(filter #(zero? (mod 6 %)) (range 1 (inc 6)))  ;;=> (1 2 3 6)
```

but putting the `#`  right before the `(mod 6 %)` will cause an error. Is there a rule where in such a context my anonymous function begins, and why should the `#` come before `(zero? ...`?

Comment: Better stick to the [`(fn [...] ...)`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(fn%20name?%20[params*%20]%20exprs*)) form of the anonymous function if you find the equivalent [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) `#(... )` unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure's `filter` function takes one or two arguments; either way, the first argument must be a *function*. So there's no "rule" where the anonymous function is defined, as long as ultimately, the first argument to `filter` is a function.

However, in this case, `zero?` does not return a function, so `(zero? #(mod 6 %))` would cause `filter` to throw an error. And, in fact, `(zero? #(mod 6 %)` doesn't make sense, either, because `zero?` does not take a function as an argument.

Comment: so `zero?` returns a Boolean and that's the problem with it, right?

Answer (score 7):

This shows how the #(...) syntax is just a shorthand for (fn [x] ...):

```
(defn divides-6 [arg]
  (zero? (mod 6 arg)))

(println  (filter divides-6                   (range 1 10))) ; normal function
(println  (filter (fn [x] (zero? (mod 6 x)))  (range 1 10))) ; anonymous function
(println  (filter        #(zero? (mod 6 %))   (range 1 10))) ; shorthand version

;=> (1 2 3 6)
;=> (1 2 3 6)
;=> (1 2 3 6)
```

Using `defn` is just shorthand for `(def divides-6 (fn [x] ...))` (i.e. the `def` and `fn` parts are combined into `defn` to save a little typing). We don't need to define a global name `divides-6` if we are only going to use the function once.  We can just define the function inline right where it will be used.  The `#(...)` syntax is just a shorthand version as the example shows.

Note that the full name of the form `#(...)` is the "anonymous function literal".  You may also see it called the "function reader macro" or just the "function macro".  The syntax `(fn [x] ...)` is called the "function special form".

Comment: Note: You can use `(read-string "#(zero? (mod 6 %))")
=> (fn* [p1__29403#] (zero? (mod 6 p1__29403#)))` to show that `#()` gets expanded to a function by the reader.

Answer (score 4):

**filter** takes two parameters:

- a predicate (a filter, which is a function), and
- a collection

So, in a simple way:

```
(defn my-predicate [x]
 (zero? (mod 6 x)))

(def my-collection
 (range 1 (inc 6)))

(filter 
 my-filter 
 my-collection)
```

**#** is a clojure macro, or something that preprocess and reorganize code for you. We can see the result of a macro with macroexpand-1 :

```
 (macroexpand-1 '#(zero? (mod 6 %)))
 ; (fn* [p1__4777#] (zero? (mod 6 p1__4777#)))
```

or in a more readable code:

```
 (fn* [x] 
   (zero? 
     (mod 6 x))
```

On a single value of a collection, say 3, we can apply the above function:

```
 ( (fn* [x] 
     (zero? 
       (mod 6 x))) 
   3)
 ; true
```

And then back to the *#* version of our code, the input parameter of a function is implicitly %, so:

```
 ( 
   #(zero? (mod 6 %))
   3) 
 ; true
```

And finally, back to your original function, you see why *#* needs to be the function defining the predicate for the filter function:

```
 (filter 
   #(zero? (mod 6 %)) 
   (range 1 (inc 6))) 
 ; (1 2 3 6)
```